# Flutter Geo location error in Address and App Data file

Tags: android, flutter, dart, geolocation

Used Flutter 2.2.2
Android studio - 4.2.1

*This is my appData.dart file code*
have error in class address.have issue in save location.

```
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    import 'package:riderapp/Models/address.dart';
    
    class AppData extends ChangeNotifier
    {
       Address pickUpLocation;
    
      void updatePickUpLocationAddress(Address pickUpAddress)
      {
        pickUpLocation = pickUpAddress;
        notifyListeners();
      }
    }
```

**This is my address.dart file**
have error in address line

```
    class Address
    {
      String placeFormattedAddress;
      String placeName;
      String placeId;
      double latitude;
      double longitude;
    
    
      Address({this.placeFormattedAddress, this.placeName, this.placeId, this.latitude, this.longitude});
    }
```

Comment: What is the error to be exact?

Comment: error: Non-nullable instance field 'pickUpLocation' must be initialized. (not_initialized_non_nullable_instance_field at [riderapp] lib/DataHandler/appData.dart:6)

Comment: error: The parameter 'placeId' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'. (missing_default_value_for_parameter at [riderapp] lib/Models/address.dart:10)

Comment: error: The parameter 'placeName' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'. (missing_default_value_for_parameter at [riderapp] lib/Models/address.dart:10)

Comment: error: The parameter 'latitude' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'. (missing_default_value_for_parameter at [riderapp] lib/Models/address.dart:10)

Comment: error: The parameter 'longitude' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'. (missing_default_value_for_parameter at [riderapp] lib/Models/address.dart:10)

Comment: error: The parameter 'placeFormattedAddress' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'. (missing_default_value_for_parameter at [riderapp] lib/Models/address.dart:10)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, this comes from the new null-safety features introduced in dart 2.0. I would recommend checking the [official dev docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/null-safety) for more information.

You have two options.

#### 1: Make them all nullable using ?

Therefore, your code will look like (only address.dart)

```
    class Address
    {
      String? placeFormattedAddress;
      String? placeName;
      String? placeId;
      double? latitude;
      double? longitude;
    
    
      Address({this.placeFormattedAddress, this.placeName, this.placeId, this.latitude, this.longitude});
    }
```

However this may lead to more issues in the future regarding null-safety checks.

#### 2: Initialize them with a default value to prevent initialization being null.

```
    class Address
    {
      String placeFormattedAddress = '';
      String placeName = '';
      String placeId = '';
      double latitude = 0.0;
      double longitude = 0.0;
    
    
      Address({this.placeFormattedAddress, this.placeName, this.placeId, this.latitude, this.longitude});
    }
```

Comment: what for this error ?Address pickUpLocation;

Comment: Just add Address pickUpLocation = Address(); Address would be the default constructor here. If the answer helped don't forget to accept by hitting the green checkmark near the question and upvoting

Comment: error in mainscreen.dart after use this code Provider.of<AppData>(context).pickUpLocation != null
                                ? Provider.of<AppData>(context).pickUpLocation.placeName
                                : "Add Home"

Comment: This seems to be a completely different question that talks about the provider package that you use. For one, I do not know how your main screen.dart file looks like.

Comment: after this code not work properly      class Address
    {
      String placeFormattedAddress = '';
      String placeName = '';
      String placeId = '';
      double latitude = 0.0;
      double longitude = 0.0;
    
    
      Address({this.placeFormattedAddress, this.placeName, this.placeId, this.latitude, this.longitude});
    }

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
Address pickUpLocation = Address(placeFormattedAdress:'',placeName:'',placeId:'',latitude:0.0,longitude:0.0);
```

This actually solved my issue and the code run perfectly.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.